# Json.net circular reference exception even with JsonSerializerSettings

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm trying to serialize my product object but my program keeps crashing. This is probably due to my ProductPropertyValue and PropertyValue circular reference. But as you can see from my JSON, there isn't actually a circular reference in my JSON, just the possibility for there to be one.

Of course I tried to find a solution before posting my question. Most of the answers I found included some variation of these JsonSerializerSettings: `ReferenceLoopHandling` and `PreserveReferencesHandling`. But no matter what settings I try to set, nothing works.

Am I missing something obvious or is there a better solution for what I'm trying to do?

***JSON***

```
{
    "id": "skdlfkioajzze",
    "properties": [{
        "id": "skdlfkioajzzf",
        "name": "Population",
        "value": 1000
    }, {
        "id": "skdlfkioajzzg",
        "name": "Weight",
        "value": 72.41
    }, {
        "id": "skdlfkioajzzh",
        "name": "Appendages",
        "values": [{
            "id": "skdlfkioajzzi",
            "name": "Legs",
            "value": 2
        }, {
            "id": "skdlfkioajzzj",
            "name": "Heads",
            "value": 1
        }]
    }, {
        "id": "skdlfkioajzzk",
        "name": "Species",
        "value": "Human"
    }]
}
```

***Serialization code***

```
string json;
try
{
    Product product = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>(json);
    var reserializedJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product, new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize,
        PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects
    });
    Product redeserializedJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>(reserializedJson);
    Debug.Log(reserializedJson);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Debug.Log(e.Message);
}
```

***Product model***

```
public class Product
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public List<ProductPropertyValue> Properties { get; set; }
}
```

***ProductPropertyValue class***

```
public class ProductPropertyValue
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string PropertyId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public PropertyValue ValueObject { get; set; 
}
```

***PropertyValue model***

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(PropertyValueConverter))]
public class PropertyValue
{
    public string StringValue { get; set; }
    public int IntValue { get; set; }
    public float FloatValue { get; set; }
    public List<ProductPropertyValue> ListValue { get; set; }

    public PropertyValue()
    {
        IntValue = int.MaxValue;
        FloatValue = float.MaxValue;
    }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public string Value
    {
        get
        {
            if (IntValue != int.MaxValue)
            {
                return IntValue.ToString();
            }

            if (FloatValue != float.MaxValue)
            {
                return FloatValue.ToString();
            }

            return StringValue;
        }
    }
}
```

***PropertyValueConverter model***

```
public class PropertyValueConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return (objectType == typeof(PropertyValue));
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JToken jObject = JToken.Load(reader);
        PropertyValue propertyValue = new PropertyValue();
        switch (reader.TokenType)
        {
            case JsonToken.Float:
                propertyValue.FloatValue = jObject.ToObject<float>();
                break;
            case JsonToken.Integer:
                propertyValue.IntValue = jObject.ToObject<int>();
                break;
            case JsonToken.String:
                propertyValue.StringValue = jObject.ToObject<string>();
                break;
            case JsonToken.EndArray:
            case JsonToken.StartArray:
                propertyValue.ListValue = new List<ProductPropertyValue>();
                List<JToken> tokens = jObject.ToList();
                foreach (JToken token in tokens)
                {
                    ProductPropertyValue prop = token.ToObject<ProductPropertyValue>();
                    if (prop != null)
                    {
                        propertyValue.ListValue.Add(prop);
                    }
                }
                break;
        }

        return propertyValue;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        try
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, value);
        }
        catch (JsonWriterException)
        {
            Debug.Log("caught json writer exception");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.Log("caught exception " + e.Message);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: JSON string you shared in question is wrong

Comment: @GaurangDave fixed

Comment: It is clear that there is no self reference in this json because single value has "value" keyname and where there is a object, keyname is "values". I tried creating classes from this json and its working for me.

Comment: Have you tried with this option `ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;`? Setting it to Ignore solved the issues for me in another application

Comment: Check this fiddle http://rextester.com/JQGC85829 . I just created it to test.

Comment: @GaurangDave of course if you remove the circular reference there isn't an issue anymore, your fiddle leaves out the most crucial part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I solved the crashes! The issue was that my custom JsonConverter kept calling itself in an infinite loop. I had to move my `[JsonConverter(typeof(PropertyValueConverter))]` annotation from the PropertyValue model to the ProductPropertyValue model.

This is what my code looks like now:

***ProductPropertyValue class***

```
public class ProductPropertyValue
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string PropertyId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("value")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(PropertyValueConverter))]
    public PropertyValue ValueObject { get; set; 
}
```

***PropertyValue model***

```
public class PropertyValue
{
    public string StringValue { get; set; }
    public int IntValue { get; set; }
    public float FloatValue { get; set; }
    public List<ProductPropertyValue> ListValue { get; set; }

    public PropertyValue()
    {
        IntValue = int.MaxValue;
        FloatValue = float.MaxValue;
    }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public string Value
    {
        get
        {
            if (IntValue != int.MaxValue)
            {
                return IntValue.ToString();
            }

            if (FloatValue != float.MaxValue)
            {
                return FloatValue.ToString();
            }

            return StringValue;
        }
    }
}
```